# Constructor parameters and value object implementation choices

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I can't wrap my head around one dilemma.

1. If i model my `ValueObjects` as c# `records` i end up in problems because of `with {Property = something}` because in that case auto-generated `init` properties might circumvent some logic enforced in constructor, e.g.
2. If i model them as regular classes, then i have to check if they are not null in constructors/methods that use them as parameters.
3. If i model them as `struct` (which i lean towards the most atm) then i don't have a null-check but still, i have a default value check (if its not allowed by an entity).
4. Last option i can think of is to model them as `struct` with private `isValid` property initially set to `false` which gets set to `true` in my constructor and gets checked in getters.

Are there any other options I'm missing that would hopefully make null-checks in constructors/methods that use VOs unnecessary and at the same time be truly immutable?

**[UPDATE]**

An example:

```
public LegalSubject(LegalSubjectId id,
                      GeneralInfo generalInfo,
                        VatId vatId,
                          LegalSubjectId? customerId
        {
        // LegalSubjectId cannot be null
        // GeneralInfo cannot be null
        // VatId cannot be null
}
```

Now, properties for each value object (`GeneralInfo` e.g.) are checked at the time they're created. So, for example, its enforced that `GeneralInfo.Name` is not empty, `GeneralInfo.Email` is not empty, etc... (obviously, `struct` doesn't apply here because defaults would put VO into invalid state).

What would be nice is to have a way to avoid null-checks/default-checks in this class that uses VOs.
`struct` with `isValid` (which is set in non-default constructor) solves the issue but i was hoping there is some other solution i'm missing.

PS.
If nullable reference types would be enforced (instead of just warning), that would solve it. But its not.

Comment: I think an example would be useful. Most value types I use regularly have reasonable default values. So what kind of objects do you represent that needs a high degree of validation? And is this in the context of an external API, or internal code? Each have different concerns that can be important.

Comment: @JonasH I've updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood value objects, you should not be able to have one that is invalid. They should always be valid and immutable.

So there really is no other choice than a constructor (or factory method) that checks if all parameters are valid. You seem very focussed on nulls, are you sure that is the only invalid data you could get?

If your only concern is null values, you may want to look into nullable reference types, which may make it easier.

But in the end, yes, a regular class with a constructor checking for validity of the input to build a valid, immutable object is how you build value objects.

Comment: I've looked into nullable reference types but since they're not enforced by the compiler but instead only issue a warning, i didn't find too much value in it for this particular case as they can't prevent users of my classes to send what i don't want them to send (namely, VO parameters = null, e.g.).

Comment: I'm not focused on null-checks only but if i could find a way on a language level to circumvent null-checking parameters - i'd definitely love it.  but seems just like a wet dream, atm.

Comment: Sure. Especially since "null" might not actually be the only problem. If you have an "Email" value object, an empty string for example, although not technically null, is just as invalid. So I would not treat nullability as the problem, you need to check in the constructor anyway, even for value types. `-3` might not be a valid value for `Weight.FromKilograms`.

Comment: That's a bit different thing. `Weigh.FromKilograms  = -3` is a check within the ValueObject itself and that's fine. On the other hand, method that uses `Weight`, e.g. `Body.CalculateBMI(Weight weight, Height height, Age age)` also has to check if `weight` is null. So, those are 2 different checks happening at 2 different places. I'm trying to handle the latter one. With classes i have to check if `weight==null` and with structs i need to check if its not `default` (or have that `isValid` implementation within struct).

Comment: I'm just saying that since you *have* to have validity checks in a constructor/factory method *anyway*, I would not invent a new pattern and treat null checks differently.

Comment: that's a valid point, for sure.